# ORACLE - MAX and SUM

Tags: oracle, sum, max

The below query returns a list of the most popular theatre and rowtype combinations sorted by total amount:
so for example:

```
NAME      ROWTYPE  TOTALAMOUNT
theatre1  middle   200
theatre2  front    190
theatre1  front    150
theatre2  middle   100
```

Whereas what I need is simply the maximum per theatre:

```
theatre1  middle   200
theatre2  front    190
```

Query:

```
SELECT name, rowtype, sum
from ( select
name, rowtype, sum(totalamount) sum from trow, fact, theatre

Where trow.trowid = fact.trowid
AND
theatre.theatreid = fact.theatreid

GROUP BY rowtype, name
)

ORDER BY sum DESC, name, rowtype ;
```

Comment: Please share the trow, fact and theatre table definition and purpose of using sum(totalamount)

Comment: It would be helpful if we knew which tables the NAME and ROWTYPE fields came from. I'm GUESSING that NAME is the theater name, and thus comes from THEATRE, and the row type comes from TROW, but leaves open the question of where TOTALAMOUNT comes from. Some clarification in the question would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select name, rowtype, sum
from (select name, rowtype, sum(totalamount) as sumta,
             max(sum(totalamount)) over (partition by name) as maxsumta
      from trow join
           fact
           on trow.trowid = fact.trowid join
           theatre
           on  theatre.theatreid = fact.theatreid
     group byrowtype, name
    ) nr
where sumta = maxsumta;
```

In addition, you should learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Put your current query into a common table expression and then use window functions to find the max total amount for each theatre.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT name, rowtype, SUM(totalamount) sum
    FROM trow
    INNER JOIN fact
        ON trow.trowid = fact.trowid
    INNER JOIN theatre
        ON theatre.theatreid = fact.theatreid
    GROUP BY name, rowtype
)

SELECT name, rowtype, sum
FROM
(
    SELECT name,
           rowtype,
           sum,
           MAX(sum) OVER (PARTITION BY name) maxSum
    FROM cte
) t
WHERE t.sum = t.maxSum
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment - oracle is returning the below error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: @HannahFarrugia Could you try the query again?